# Why Binary search tree?

Tags: arrays, binary-search-tree

Why do people use binary search trees? 
Why not simply do a binary search on the array sorted from lowest to highest?
To me, an insertion / deletion cost seems to be the same, why complicate life with processes such as max/min heapify etc?

Is it just because of random access required within a data structure?

Comment: You haven't given *any* context here - different data structures are used for different situations with different requirements. What situation are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of insertion is not the same.  If you want to insert an item in the middle of an array, you have to move all elements to the right of the inserted element by one position, the effort for that is proportional to the size of the array: O(N).  With a self-balancing binary tree the complexity of insertion is much lower: O(ln(N)).

Comment: Thank you!

I know that a BBST or an ordinary BST is presented in the form of an array, but because of it's properties, we can figure out at which cell to insert the new elements (fix the properties later) as you said, with the lowest cost (worst case O(ln(N))    ).

However, as I understand, BST are an array, and aren't a list.

Does this mean that a big, empty array is prepared for a tree to grow in inside, but when it gets too big and doesn't fit - we have to copy it to a new, larger array (which has many extra empty spaces for a further growth) ? 

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, to get to the lowest element in the BBST I will have to _travel by pointers_ log n times. I can't access it with an index (even if we are talking of a simple binary heap) @pentadecagon